# Change the style uniquely if files are jpg

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, styles, png, jpeg

hello in my html page I have jpg and png files all this files have a class : ".background" in this class I defined size and other attributes. I want change the attributes uniquely on jpeg files.
In JS can I find all jpg files of my page and change the style of this class ?
Thank you for your help

Comment: Now that we have a description of the code, can we see the code please?

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view you could do the following:

- First select all the  that have a src that contains ".jpg" at the end of the name (with regex or similar) and save them in a list or in a variable
- Then apply the necessary changes with `myVariable.style.X`

However without further details it's difficult to help you more. It would be much easier to help you if you could provide us more details on the code you have, could you edit your post please?

Have a nice day!